# Azure DevOps REST Api - Code Search script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to create a report which details the packages and versions my C# projects uses across many repositories stored in Azure DevOps.

My thought process is:

1. Use Azure DevOps code search to find all instances of `<PackageReference Include="`.
2. Parse that to get the package name and version.
3. Build a report.

I've found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code-search-results/fetch-code-search-results?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP but that doesn't return the line of code matched, just the location, e.g. something like:

```
"matches": {
    "content": [
        {
            "charOffset": 615,
            "length": 3,
            "line": 0,
            "column": 0,
            "codeSnippet": null,
            "type": "content"
        }
    ],
```

Is there another API to get the line of code referred to above? If not, is there a different/better way to achieve what I want?